# Dictionary is not giving all elements - Python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I want to make dictionary from lists.

```
import numpy as np

a1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
c1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']

array2 = np.array([a1,b1,c1]).tolist()

keys = ['name', 'type','description','logo']

print dict(zip(keys, zip(*array2)))
```

Output:

```
{'logo': ('4', 'd', 'D'), 'type': ('2', 'b', 'B'), 'name': ('1', 'a', 'A'), 'description': ('3', 'c', 'C')}
```

- Why am i getting only 4 elements
- Why the dictionary elements are in random order of 4,2,1,3 and why
  not 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Can you add what you want the output to look like? Right now I'm not clear.

Comment: You're getting 4 items because `keys` contains 4 elements. `dict` does not guarantee order, user `OrdererdDict` for that

Comment: yes, thanks got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why am I getting only 4 elements?

According to the [`zip` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

> The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

Since `keys` only contains 4 elements, your zipped list resulting from `zip(keys, zip(*array2))` will also contain 4 values, resulting in your `dict` only containing 4 values.

---

### Why the dictionary elements are in random order?

The order of elements in a normal dictionary is not guaranteed. I think it's implementation specific, and usually based on the order of the keys' hashes. You should use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to maintain a specific order:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict

a1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
c1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']

array2 = np.array([a1,b1,c1]).tolist()

keys = ['name', 'type','description','logo']

print OrderedDict(zip(keys, zip(*array2)))
# prints: OrderedDict([('name', ('1', 'a', 'A')), ('type', ('2', 'b', 'B')), ('description', ('3', 'c', 'C')), ('logo', ('4', 'd', 'D'))])
```